# Unity Google Play Console Warning optimize APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I uploaded a Unity game to Google Play Console. But I got this warning:

> **APK without optimization** Warning:
>
> This APK has codes and resources that are not used and that are being
>   sent to users. Reduce the size of your application with the Android
>   App Bundle. If you do not optimize your application for different
>   device configurations, it will weigh too much to download and install
>   it on users' devices. The heavier applications have a lower volume of
>   downloads. In addition, they take up a lot of storage space on users'
>   devices.
>
> Solution: Use the Android App Bundle to be automatically optimized
>   according to different device configurations or manage it with several
>   APKs.

Why it can be? In my Unity project, I have the scenes with all necessary and in Asset, I have the resources, prefabs, scripts...

I have some resources which do not use in any scene yet, it can be the problem?
And if it is, how I could fix it? I do not wanna delete resources from the project which I will use shortly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You uploaded an apk. You can upload an Android App Bundle instead by using unity:

[image]

Comment: @LiefLyaer : I am using Unity 2017.4.30, which is said to support Android Build Bundle. But, I do not see the "Build App Bundle (Google Play)" option as shown in your image. Is it because I have not enabled "App Signing" yet ? Please let me know where to find that option ? Thanks.

Comment: @Thanh I'm not sure. I don't use unity 2017 anymore. Right now I use Unity 2019. Try to contact Unity support I'm sure they will answer where to find the unity app bundle for unity 2017. You can also try to enable the app signing like you said

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. If I change the "Build System" to "Gradle", then the "Build App Bundle (Google Play)" option to show up. Does it mean I have to use "Gradle" build and NOT "internal" build ? For many reason, my game only builds with the INTERNAL and not the GRADLE option...

Comment: When I use "INTERNAL" build, I still can see inside the "Player Setting", it has the "Bundle Version Code". Does it mean it can build "Android Bundle" or not ? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that, with the INTERNAL option, I still can build bundle, but I won't be able to enable the warning option. Is it correct ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure (internal is not avaible in the new Unity 2019). Why your game do not build with Grandle? You should be able to correct that

Comment: PS. I was able to make an app bundle without the app signing play store (I have one but I'm still in the development fase so I do not use it). Just connect the device in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

The Play Console has detected that your APK includes native libraries for multiple device architectures. This means that regardless of the architecture of the device of your users, they will receive the libraries for all of them.

This is just a warning to let you know that your app is unnecessarily big and could be reduced in size by publishing an App Bundle instead of an APK (Play would then generate the APKs for you, but only serves the libraries that each device needs).

@LiefLayer has shown you in the other answer how to do it from Unity. Keep in mind however that you'll need to be enrolled in App Signing by Play before that.

You can find more information at http://g.co/androidappbundle

Hope that helps,

Comment: it will not create an issue in downloading of app by users or any other issues, if we ignore the warning?

Comment: If by issue you mean that users will get a crash, no. Users will be able to install and download the app normally. It's just a warning to let you know that your app is bigger than it could be, and the bigger the app the bigger the chances that the download fails.

Comment: @Pierre : I am using Unity 2017.4.30, which is said to support Android Build Bundle. But, I do not see the "Build App Bundle (Google Play)" option as shown in the image by "LiefLayer" below.  Is it because I have not enabled "App Signing" yet ? Please let me know where to find that option ? Thanks.

Comment: @Pierre:  Oh, I figured it out. If I change the "Build System" to "Gradle", then the "Build App Bundle (Google Play)" option to show up. Does it mean I have to use "Gradle" build and NOT "internal" build ? For many reason, my game only builds with the INTERNAL and not the GRADLE option...

Comment: @Pierre: When I use "INTERNAL" build, I still can see inside the "Player Setting", it has the "Bundle Version Code". Does it mean it can build "Android Bundle" or not ? Thanks

Comment: I guess that, with the INTERNAL option, I still can build bundle, but I won't be able to enable the warning option. Is it correct ?

Comment: The "internal build" does not support App Bundles AFAIK, only Gradle does. I suspect the "bundle version code" is unrelated to the Android App Bundles and must be about another type of bundle, maybe an [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)?